# Sqlite index creation and listing

Tags: sqlite, indexing

I have few questions to better understand indexes in sqlite

1) What is the default order of an Index?

2) What is the difference between?

```
CREATE INDEX "idx_event_pid" ON "event" (pid );
```

vs

```
CREATE INDEX "idx_event_pid" ON "event" (pid ASC );
```

3) Can index be inspected, if so how? For example: Show first 5 items of index
This helps to answer 1 & 2 as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sort order of a column is not specified, it defaults to `ASC`.

However, this does not make any difference in most cases, because the database can just as easily step backwards through an index as it can stop forward. (The exception are some multi-column indexes.)

Indexes always are transparent, i.e., they cannot be queried directly, and query results are the same, whether the index happens to be used or not.
To get the five smallest entries, just query the five smallest entries from the *table* (which contains exactly the same data).

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to inspect the index?

Comment: No; indexes are transparent, and the data is identical to that in the table.